# Fundamental group of the n-holed torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am trying to determine the fundamental group of the n-holed torus

I know that the fundamental group of the torus is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

The n-holed torus deformation retracts onto n copies of the circle linked together (i.e. an extended version of the figure 9 loop - with n loops)

What would its fundamental group be?

I am guessing something of the form $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times .... \mathbb{Z} $

Comment: I believe it is not even abelian, you can see this intuitively by noticing one can embed the n-fold figure eight(that is, a space with the same fundamental group as $\mathbb{R}^2-{x_1,..,x_n}$) in the n-fold torus. I believe (but am not sure) this induces an injection of fundamental groups, so the fundamental group of the n-fold torus has a non-abelian subgroup, hence it is not abelian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $n$-holed torus has as fundamental group the group presented as

$$\langle a_1, b_1, \ldots, a_n, b_n \mid [a_1,b_1]\cdots[a_n,b_n] = 0\rangle$$

where $[a, b] = aba^{-1}b^{-1}$.

As an example, consider this octagon:

[image: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/images/5/5e/Polygon_construction.png]

Identify all corners, then identify the edges as labeled, and you get a 2-holed torus. The sequence $a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}a_2b_2a_2^{-1}b_2^{-1}$ of edge labelings immediately gives you the generating relation for the fundamental group.

Comment: For $n=2$, is that supposed to be $[a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2] = 0$ or $[a_1,b_1] = [a_2,b_2] = 0$?

Comment: It's supposed to be $[a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2] = 0.$

Comment: Can you explain how you got this please?

Comment: Are $a_i$ and $b_i$ loops? Did you use the triangulation on simplicial complex to get this?

Comment: Edited the answer, added an example.

Comment: thanks for this, I see how you get the generators from this shape. So in the n-holed torus case would you have a polygon with many more sides? With each side corresponding to a_i or b_j?

Comment: Yes. The $4n$ sides would be labeled $a_1, b_1, a_1^{-1}, b_1^{-1}, \ldots, a_n, b_n, a_n^{-1}, b_n^{-1}$. It is clear how the interior of the polygon makes the path around the edge of the polygon nullhomotopic, right?